# Slick slider - Update current slide based on URL

Tags: jquery, html, href, slick.js

I'm facing a problem i'd like to fix.

I've got a visual navigation and would like to always have the current slide as the first slide. It should update dynamically based on the URL.

```js
   var current = window.location.href;
   $('.slider a').each(function(){
      var link = '/' + $(this).attr('href');
      if (current == link){
        $(this).parent().addClass('slick-current slick-active');
      }
   });
```

i've created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Helge12345/Ly7w6bvr/)

But it is not working - probably some of you has a better approach on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This won't work because when it might be excuted before the slider is initialised. You need to put this snippet in the "init" callback. check here https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code given below :

```
            var pageName = (function() {
                var current = window.location.href,
                    b = .lastIndexOf("/");
                return current.substr(b + 1);
            }());

             $('.slider current').each(function(){
                if ($(this).attr('href') == pageName) {
                    $(this).parents().addClass('slick-current slick-active');
                }
            });
```